# how to do corrleationId copying at route level? and only if CorrelationID is not filled

Tags: apache-camel

My Usecase (in camel):

- if incoming message has correlationId (say clientCorrId) => leave as such, do nothing, as clientCorrId is used by client to map response.
- if incoming message do not have correlationId => take messageId and put it in correlationId (at route level, not in every route that uses "jms" component)

Copying correlationId should be done only at a route level

How to do corrleationId copying at route level? (not globally as in useMessageIDAsCorrelationID as below)

```
<bean id="jms" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
    <!--property name="useMessageIDAsCorrelationID" value="true" / WARNING! Do not use this as we need to copy only in the beginning not everywhere -->
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="jpaTransactionManager" />
    <property name="transacted" value="true" />
</bean>
```

I want to avoid having a separate bean code like this to copy correlationId **ONLYIF it is empty**:

```
    if (EMPTY_MSG_ID.equals(currentCorrId)) {
        log.info("No corrId set, setting msgId to corrid :" + msgId);
        outHeader.put(correlationIdKey, msgId);
    } else {
        outHeader.put(correlationIdKey, currentCorrId);
        log.info("CorrId already set: " + currentCorrId);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an interceptor to intercept from jms endpoints, and add the missing id if needed. See http://camel.apache.org/intercept